# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint error

Tags: database, apache-age

I am trying to insert data into Apache Age table, and I am getting this error which says,’duplicate key value violates unique constraint’.

I have an existing Apache Age database and a table with a unique constraint defined on one or more columns. I'm using the following SQL statement to insert data into the table:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3, val4);
```

I expected the data to be inserted into the table without any issues.

I'm getting a 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint' error.

Comment: Have you added primary key constrains in the table? having the primary key will also force a unique constraint.

Comment: Please add the `table` data to your question. It'd be best for other users to reference later if they have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem there are many cases that could be the issue for the problem, but generally, you get the **duplicate key value violates unique constraint** error when you try to insert a duplicate value into a column that has a **unique** constraint. Take for example you have a column called **email** which should always be **unique**, when you try to add **example@example.com** twice you will get that error you see. So to solve you problem, simply understand the constraints of the columns you are dealing with, and avoid inserting duplicate values for columns have **unique** constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error occurs when you try to insert data that already exists in a column that you defined as with a unique constraint. Verify if you are trying to insert data that generates this conflict. You can also use the `ON CONFLICT` clause to specify what to do in case of conflict. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3, val4)
ON CONFLICT (col1) DO <option>;
```

Replace `<option>` with the action to solve the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a column value that is already exists in the database and because you have specified that one of the columns have `UNIQUE` constraint this error appears.

You can't insert a duplicate value for a column with `UNIQUE` constraint and this error is not related to `AGE` extension.

If you want to drop the `UNIQUE` constraint from any column you can do so by running the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurs when you are trying to insert a new record into a table that has the *unique* constraint on one or more columns and the value you are trying to insert already exists.

Possible Solutions:

1. Remove the unique constraint
2. Change the value you are inserting

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others you are trying to insert the key value pair that is already there in the database. So, to resolve this you can you can make some changes with your table by

- Removing this unique value constraint.
- You can change the data that you are trying to insert in the table.
- If you are doing it for **practice purpose** you can delete the
  previous database and add your new data.

Answer (score 0):

Lookingat your query you might be putting in a primary key int the column that already exists. You might want to check if that key exists instead of adding values replace them in the corresponding row. If it is due to some other constraint you can simply drop that constarint using

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT constraintname;
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when you try inserting the same value again in a column where only unique values should exist. So in order to resolve this issue, you should change the value you are trying to insert.
Moreover, you could also remove the unique constraint from the table so as to not face this issue only when the column can have the same multiple values.
e.g. in the case of age(column), multiple people can have the same age, but their ID(Let's say another column) has to have a unique constraint because multiple people cannot have the same ID.

So in your case, there might be a value already present in any of the columns that you are trying to add again.
Hopefully, this explains.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to insert a value that already exists in a column with a unique constraint. To fix this ensure the values you're inserting are unique or modify the constraint if needed.

For instance, while age can have duplicates, ID should remain unique. 
Check the constraints on your columns and avoid inserting duplicate values to resolve the issue.